# El módulo pyodbc me devuelve un error de pocos parametro en el execute

Tags: python-3.x

Tengo un problema que al intentar actualizar mi base de datos access (.mdb) me devuelve un error de que me faltan parametros en el execute, cuando de hecho los paso correctamente.

Mi fracción de código:

```
# Se actualiza la base de datos.
 
    cursor.execute("UPDATE [Inquilinos] SET [Domicilio_alquiler] = ? WHERE [Inquilino_id] = ?", clientes[index_seleccionado][2], clientes[index_seleccionado][0])      
    cursor.execute("UPDATE [Inquilinos] SET [Numero_telefono] = ? WHERE [Inquilino_id] = ?", clientes[index_seleccionado][3], clientes[index_seleccionado][0])       
    cursor.execute("UPDATE [Inquilinos] SET [Monto_Alquiler] = ? WHERE [Inquilino_id] = ?", clientes[index_seleccionado][4], clientes[index_seleccionado][0])      
    cursor.execute("UPDATE [Inquilinos] SET [Monto_deposito_numero] = ? WHERE [Inquilino_id] = ?", clientes[index_seleccionado][5], clientes[index_seleccionado][0])      
    cursor.execute("UPDATE [Inquilinos] SET [Fecha_inicio_contrato] = ? WHERE [Inquilino_id] = ?", fecha_inicio, clientes[index_seleccionado][0])      
    cursor.execute("UPDATE [Inquilinos] SET [Fecha_fin_contrato] = ? WHERE [Inquilino_id] = ?", fecha_final, clientes[index_seleccionado][0])       
    cursor.execute("UPDATE [Inquilinos] SET [Propietario] = ? WHERE [Inquilino_id] = ?", clientes[index_seleccionado][8], clientes[index_seleccionado][0])       
    cursor.execute("UPDATE [Inquilinos] SET [Tipo_comision] = ? WHERE [Inquilino_id] = ?", clientes[index_seleccionado][9], clientes[index_seleccionado][0])      
    cursor.execute("UPDATE [Inquilinos] SET [Monto_comision] = ? WHERE [Inquilino_id] = ?", clientes[index_seleccionado][10], clientes[index_seleccionado][0])      
    cursor.execute("UPDATE [Inquilinos] SET [Aguas_cuota] = ? WHERE [Inquilino_id] = ?", clientes[index_seleccionado][11], clientes[index_seleccionado][0])        
    cursor.execute("UPDATE [Inquilinos] SET [Aguas_Importe] = ? WHERE [Inquilino_id] = ?", clientes[index_seleccionado][12], clientes[index_seleccionado][0])        
    cursor.execute("UPDATE [Inquilinos] SET [Porcentual_agua_e_imp] = ? WHERE [Inquilino_id] = ?", clientes[index_seleccionado][13], clientes[index_seleccionado][0])        
    cursor.execute("UPDATE [Inquilinos] SET [Quien_paga_Agua] = ? WHERE [Inquilino_id] = ?", clientes[index_seleccionado][14], clientes[index_seleccionado][0])        
    cursor.execute("UPDATE [Inquilinos] SET [Muni_Cuota] = ? WHERE [Inquilino_id] = ?", clientes[index_seleccionado][15], clientes[index_seleccionado][0])        
    cursor.execute("UPDATE [Inquilinos] SET [Muni_Importe] = ? WHERE [Inquilino_id] = ?", clientes[index_seleccionado][16], clientes[index_seleccionado][0])       
    cursor.execute("UPDATE [Inquilinos] SET [Quien_paga_Muni] = ? WHERE [Inquilino_id] = ?", clientes[index_seleccionado][17], clientes[index_seleccionado][0])       
    cursor.execute("UPDATE [Inquilinos] SET [Rentas_cuota] = ? WHERE [Inquilino_id] = ?", clientes[index_seleccionado][18], clientes[index_seleccionado][0])       
    cursor.execute("UPDATE [Inquilinos] SET [Rentas_Importe] = ? WHERE [Inquilino_id] = ?", clientes[index_seleccionado][19], clientes[index_seleccionado][0])        
    cursor.execute("UPDATE [Inquilinos] SET [Quien_paga_rentas] = ? WHERE [Inquilino_id] = ?", clientes[index_seleccionado][20], clientes[index_seleccionado][0])       
    cursor.execute("UPDATE [Inquilinos] SET [Monto_unico_agua_e_imp] = ? WHERE [Inquilino_id] = ?", clientes[index_seleccionado][21], clientes[index_seleccionado][0])       
    cursor.execute("UPDATE [Inquilinos] SET [Mes_Expensa] = ? WHERE [Inquilino_id] = ?", clientes[index_seleccionado][22], clientes[index_seleccionado][0])        
    cursor.execute("UPDATE [Inquilinos] SET [Monto_Expensa] = ? WHERE [Inquilino_id] = ?", clientes[index_seleccionado][23], clientes[index_seleccionado][0])        
    cursor.execute("UPDATE [Inquilinos] SET [Adicional_pagares] = ? WHERE [Inquilino_id] = ?", clientes[index_seleccionado][24], clientes[index_seleccionado][0])       
    cursor.execute("UPDATE [Inquilinos] SET [Cuenta_y_orden] = ? WHERE [Inquilino_id] = ?", clientes[index_seleccionado][25], clientes[index_seleccionado][0])        
    cursor.execute("UPDATE [Inquilinos] SET [Libre] = ? WHERE [Inquilino_id] = ?", clientes[index_seleccionado][26], clientes[index_seleccionado][0])        
    cursor.execute("UPDATE [Inquilinos] SET [catastro] = ? WHERE [Inquilino_id] = ?", clientes[index_seleccionado][27], clientes[index_seleccionado][0])       
    cursor.execute("UPDATE [Inquilinos] SET [rentas] = ? WHERE [Inquilino_id] = ?", clientes[index_seleccionado][28], clientes[index_seleccionado][0])        
    cursor.execute("UPDATE [Inquilinos] SET [Aguas_cordobesas] = ? WHERE [Inquilino_id] = ?", clientes[index_seleccionado][29], clientes[index_seleccionado][0])        
    cursor.execute("UPDATE [Inquilinos] SET [conceptos_incluidos] = ? WHERE [Inquilino_id] = ?", clientes[index_seleccionado][30], clientes[index_seleccionado][0])        
    cursor.execute("UPDATE [Inquilinos] SET [Paga_x_transf] = ? WHERE [Inquilino_id] = ?", clientes[index_seleccionado][31], clientes[index_seleccionado][0])
    cursor.execute("UPDATE [Inquilinos] SET [URL_Aguas_Cbesas] = ? WHERE [Inquilino_id] = ?", clientes[index_seleccionado][32], clientes[index_seleccionado][0])
    conn.commit()
```

Y el error que me devuelve:

```
File "c:\Users\manue\Desktop\Inmo_Management\main_code.py", line 337, in aplicar
    cursor.execute("UPDATE [Inquilinos] SET [Domicilio_alquiler] = ? WHERE [Inquilino_id] = ?", clientes[index_seleccionado][2], clientes[index_seleccionado][0])
pyodbc.Error: ('07002', '[07002] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 3. (-3010) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

Cualquier tipo de ayuda me serviría. Desde ya, gracias!

Comment: Prueba a pasar los parámetros en una tupla. O sea `cursor.execute("cadena SQL", (param1, param2))`

Comment: usa `cursor.execute("UPDATE [Inquilinos] SET [Domicilio_alquiler] = ? WHERE [Inquilino_id] = ?", [clientes[index_seleccionado][2], clientes[index_seleccionado][0]])`